# WooCommerce restore stock on order cancel

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have built an store on WooCommerce, I've used [WC Cancel Order](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/wc-cancel-order) plugin to implement Cancel Order functionality for COD as well. But when any user requests for cancellation and even after it's approved by the admin, the quantity of the product does not restore.

Comment: As i know WC doesn't restore stock, after canceling order.
There was a plugin but it is outdated for 2 years now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried [WC Cancel Order](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wc-cancel-order/) recently and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Use this plugin:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-auto-restore-stock/

I has worked well for me.

Comment: It didn't worked for me.